# String Query for java API dosen’t find some documents by name

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

First, sorry for my poor english, but let me try to explain my problem.

I'm working in an application using elasticsearch java api for managed my documents. 
Everything works fine, i'm able to search in DB and save on my index, i can count my documents aggregate by field and a lot of cool things, but i stucked on a weird problem.

When i trying to search my document by field called name, some documents doesn't return on search.

Let me give an example:

My documents is look like this(just for example):

id: 1
name: book
type: pdf

id: 2
name: Test of my search service
type: zip

When i trying to search, if i search by name, send as parameter the value "book", it works fine, but when i trying to search, send my parameter value "service", the result is empty.

Here my search code:

```
SearchRequestBuilder src1 = client.prepareSearch().setQuery(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(parameter).field("name"));
```

Anyone knows, why this search doesn't find my parameter value "service" on name field of document with id 2?

Thanks!

Additional information:

My general index information:

```
 {
    "template": "*",
    "settings": {
        "index.refresh_interval": "5s"
    },
    "mappings": {
        "_default_": {
            "_all": {
                "enabled": true
            },
            "dynamic_templates": [
                {
                    "string_fields": {
                        "match": "*",
                        "match_mapping_type": "string",
                        "mapping": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "omit_norms": true,
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "properties": {
                "@version": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you add mapping info? how do you index your information? via elasticsearch-plugin?

Comment: Hi @VladislavKysliy, sorry for the missing infos. 
I index my information using elasticsearch java api, so, my application create and index it for me automatically and i don't set any mapping settings at this point.

I have a configuration to all of my index to set all string fields to not analyse(to avoid split string value on index step), into this configuration exist a mapping section:

Comment: "dynamic_templates": [
                {
                    "string_fields": {
                        "match": "*",
                        "match_mapping_type": "string",
                        "mapping": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "omit_norms": true,
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]

Comment: please, edit your post and add this information in your question with request

Comment: @VladislavKysliy done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after searching for hours and hours, i solved my problem.

To solve this issue, i used the wildcards query from elasticsearch java api and now i'm able to search a string parameter in my fields.

Here's the code:

```
SearchRequestBuilder srch1 = client.prepareSearch()
                .setIndices("index_name")
                .setTypes("type_name")
                .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_AND_FETCH)
                .setQuery(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("field_name", "*"+string_parameter+"*"));
```

After construction of your **SearchRequestBuilder** just add it into your **MultipleSearchResponse** or **SearchResponse**:

```
MultiSearchResponse sr = client.prepareMultiSearch()
                    .add(srch1)
                    .add(srch2)
                    .add(srch3)
                    .execute().actionGet();
```

In my case, i have 3 distinct queries, so i used MultipleSearchResponse.